# set the DataGridTextColumn visibilty based on property returned through ViewModel. following MVVM Caliburn

Tags: c#, wpf, mvvm

set the DataGridTextColumn visibilty based on property returned through ViewModel. 
I added the below code in View

```
xmlns:shared="clr-namespace:IKEA.CountryRange.Local.Shared"
<Window.Resources><shared:VisibilityConverterx:Key="BoolToVisibilityConverter"></shared:VisibilityConverter>
</Window.Resources>

<DataGridTextColumn Header="Price" Width="auto" Visibility="{Binding _ViewPurchasePrices, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"/>
```

Created a class in shared folder

```
public class VisibilityConverter : IValueConverter
    {

        #region IValueConverter Members

        public object Convert(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            var v = value;

            if (v == "true")
                return "Visible";
            else
                return "Collapsed";

        }

        public object ConvertBack(object value, Type targetType, object parameter, System.Globalization.CultureInfo culture)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }

        #endregion
    }

}
```

In ViewModel I have binded the Boolean value of Property.

But this code didn't worked. Please suggest on this.

Comment: How does the property you are binding to look like (ViewModel)? What property are you binding (View)? What does the `{Binding}` expression look like?

Comment: I doubt this `v == "true"` never is true, so the Visibility is always collapsed. If the property is a boolean you need to cast `value` to `bool` and check it against `true` not `"true"`.

Comment: Visibility="{Binding _ViewPurchasePrices , Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}" . _ViewPurchasePrices is assigned through ViewModel, based on some condition Property is set as true or false

Comment: What type does the ViewModel property `_ViewPurchasePrices` have?

Answer (score 1):

Since `DataGridTextColumn` or any other supported data grid columns are not part of visual tree of datagrid so they don't inherit the DataContext of datagrid/windnow. Since, they don't lie in visual tree so any try to get DataContext using RelativeSource won't work.

You can create a proxy element to bind the data context of user control/window; use that proxy element to bind the visibility of DataGridTextColumn.
For ex :

```
 <Grid>
       <Grid.Resources>
           <FrameworkElement x:Key="ProxyElement" DataContext="{Binding}"></FrameworkElement>
       </Grid.Resources>
       <ContentControl Visibility="Collapsed" Content="{StaticResource ProxyElement}"></ContentControl>
       <DataGrid>
           <DataGrid.Columns>
                <DataGridTextColumn Visibility="{Binding Source={StaticResource ProxyElement}, Path=DataContext._ViewPurchasePrices, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVisibilityConverter}}"></DataGridTextColumn>
                </DataGrid.Columns>
       </DataGrid>
    </Grid>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
var v = value as bool?; // null if not a boolean

if (v == true)
    return Visibility.Visible;
else
    return Visibility.Collapsed;
```

Answer (score -1):

Why do you not bind the visibility property of DataGridTextColumn? Then you don't need the Converter.

Comment: I don't want Visibility to be hardcoded, based on condition column need to be visible.